# How to make certain characters read-only in a Django charfield?

Tags: django, django-models, readonly

I'm trying to create a charfield in my model with a prefix read-only characters:

```
class Leader(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slack_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True, default="@slack.com")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In this model, I'm finding a way to make my `slack_id` instance to have a prefix read-only character '@' so that my users only have to fill out their username without the symbol, mimicking the way gmail sign up form below.[image]

Comment: I would take another road to accomplish this, Just leave it empty, make the fronted tell the user they don't have to use the "@" and later on connect the given name with your part. @Google.com or whatever

Answer (score 1):

That's not actually an input field. Google have developed a whole series of Javascript widgets which mimic the behaviour of browser-native inputs, with additional functionality such as the one you mention.

You would need to write your own Javascript-powered input, or find an existing one that provides the functionality you want.